# Use of *this as a return value

Tags: c++

One example from Sutter & Alexandrescu's coding standards caught my eye
"Example 2: `std::string::append` (postcondition error). When appending a character to a string, failure to allocate a new buffer if the existing one is full prevents the operation from performing its documented function and achieving its documented post-conditions, and is therefore an error."

I can't imagine that in any normal conditions one would check the return value from an append, but was curious what that value is and it turns out to be `*this` (which can only be used inside a nonstatic member function).  I suppose one could check the string length before and after the append,
but how might one go about accessing `*this`?

For example:

```
std::string::s = "Hello World";
for (int i=0; i<many millions; ++i) {
  s.append(s);
}
s.append(".");  //  Which we assume fails due to a buffer error.
```

Comment: The return value isn't for checking. It is for using.

Comment: I think the return value is there so that you can write things such as `std::cout << s.append("Something");`.

Comment: Can't you also use the return value to chain method calls?  Such as `s.append("Something").append(" another string");` ?

Comment: The possibilities are endless :-)

Comment: As well as `substr()` and other useful functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error checking in facilities like `string` as well as most of the standard library is done via exceptions, not via return values.

If `append` fails, it will exit via an exception, otherwise, the operation succeeded and you get a valid return value.  So checking for errors in the returned value is neither necessary nor possible.

As pointed out in the comments, said return value can then be used to e.g. chain operations.

Comment: It's more correct to say: "It will _leave the control_ via an exception".

Comment: @black I do not quite see how this would be more correct, what is wrong with "exit"?

Comment: Because that's what exceptions do: leave the current program control flow. Exceptions themselves don't "exit" anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to, you could cache the return value in a local variable in the loop and check it's contents, but it would be redundant:

```
std::string s = "Hello World";
for (int i=0; i<many millions; ++i)
{
  std::string s2 = s.append(s);
  if (s2.size() == 42)
  {
    break;  // or some kind of check
            // but as others said, exceptions are better
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: I am more familiar with pure C and Java than C++, if I made a mistake with syntax (wasn't sure if the cached value should be a pointer or reference, or just a string), someone can feel sure to verify my code example, or fix it.